# Threading in Python results in Globals setting to None

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, global-variables

In a python 2.7 script of mine, I have discovered this issue where threads at random instances will see the global variables all as None type and throw an error.

In trying to narrow down the issue, I limited my number of threads to 1 (plus main thread for managing threads and what data to process).  Then in running my script which does not change global variables at all, they are static, I find at random instances during the execution it throwing then the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Then that error was what brought me to the view of all of my globals.  And agian to reiterate, in no where in the code am I setting these variables.  For example, jiraIDs is an import that is an array that is utilized, not ever set.

Let me know if any other information would be needed.

[image: Globals are set None]

Main script:

```
from Jira import Jira, jiraIDs, getSearchQueryTemplate
import re, sys, time
import threading

restAPI = "JIRA URL"
validationTicket = "XYZ-01234"


def interactive():
    while(1):
        while(1):
            ticket = raw_input("Enter JIRA ID of ticket to flow EPIC Link down (eg. XYZ-XXXXX): ").strip().upper()
            if re.search('XYZ-[0-9]{5}', ticket):
                break
            print("Following is not a correct ID: {}".format(ticket))
        jira = Jira(restAPI, validationTicket)
        jira.randRequestDeley = 0
        epicFlowdownHelper(jira, ticket)
        raw_input("Finished.  Press ENTER to go again (Epic'ly)...")

def unattendedEpicflowdown():
    # For flowing down epics for the new standard of XY.BZ standard
    # filtering through epic links
    jira = Jira(restAPI,validationTicket)
    query = getSearchQueryTemplate()
    query["jql"] = 'project = "jql filter" and type = Epic and status != CLOSED'
    resp = jira.request_POST_search(query)
    epicLinks = []
    for issue in resp["issues"]:
        if  not re.search("[0-9]{1,2}\.B[1-8]|v6\.6\.1", issue["fields"]["summary"]):
            continue
        epicLinks.append(issue["key"])
    
    # get all WP's that are associated to epics in epicLinks and start the flowdown
    query["jql"] = 'project = "jql filter" and status != CLOSED and type = "Work Package" and "Epic Link" in (' + ','.join(epicLinks) + ')'
    resp = jira.request_POST_search(query)
    threads = []
    for issue in resp["issues"]:
        # epicFlowdownHelper(jira, issue['key'])
        while(len(threads) > 0):
            time.sleep(.2)
            for thread in threads:
                if( not thread.isAlive()):
                    threads.remove(thread)
        t = threading.Thread(target=epicFlowdownHelper, args=(jira, issue['key'], jiraIDs))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

def epicFlowdownHelper(jiraInstance, WorkPackage, jiraIDs):
    def updateEpicLink(jiraInstance, ticket, epicLink, resp):
        ttype = jiraIDs["type"](jiraInstance, resp).upper()
        if (ttype == "WORK ELEMENT" or ttype == "STORY") and \
                jiraIDs["status"](jiraInstance, resp).upper() != "CLOSED" and \
                jiraIDs["Epic Link"](jiraInstance, resp) != epicLink:
            print("Updating Epic for ticket: {}".format(ticket))
            data = {}
            jiraIDs["Epic Link"](jiraInstance, data, epicLink)
            jiraInstance.request_PUT(ticket, data)

    resp = jiraInstance.request_GET(WorkPackage)
    if jiraIDs["type"](jiraInstance, resp) != "Work Package":
        print("Following ticket is not a Work Package: {}".format(WorkPackage))
        return
    if jiraIDs["status"](jiraInstance,resp).upper() == "CLOSED":
        print("Following Work Package is Closed: {}".format(WorkPackage))
        return
    epicLink = jiraIDs["Epic Link"](jiraInstance, resp)
    print("Flowing down ticket Epic'ly: {}".format(WorkPackage))
    blockedByIDs = jiraIDs["is blocked by"](jiraInstance, resp)
    if not blockedByIDs:
        return
    blockedByIDs = blockedByIDs.split(',')
    for ticket in blockedByIDs:
        resp = jiraInstance.request_GET(ticket)
        if jiraIDs["type"](jiraInstance, resp).upper() not in ("WORK ELEMENT", "STORY"):
            continue
        updateEpicLink(jiraInstance, ticket, epicLink, resp)
        blockedByIDs = jiraIDs["is blocked by"](jiraInstance, resp)
        if not blockedByIDs or len(blockedByIDs) == 0:
            continue
        blockedByIDs = blockedByIDs.split(',')
        for ticket in blockedByIDs:
            resp = jiraInstance.request_GET(ticket)
            updateEpicLink(jiraInstance, ticket, epicLink, resp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1].upper() == "INTERACTIVE":
        interactive()
    else:
        unattendedEpicflowdown()
```

Jira Script:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, HTTPError
from urllib import urlencode
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
import getpass, json, os.path, copy, random, time

class Jira():

    randRequestDeley = 0

    def __init__(self, RESTuri, validationTicketID, auth=None):
        self.RESTuri = RESTuri
        self.validationTicketID = validationTicketID
        self.scriptPath = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        self.authenticationB64(auth)

    def authenticationB64(self, auth=None):
        if auth == None:
            uname = raw_input("User Name:").strip()
            passwd = getpass.getpass("Password:").strip()
        else:
            uname = auth["username"]
            passwd = auth["password"]
        self.b64Auth = b64encode(uname + ":" + passwd)
        self.request_GET(self.validationTicketID)


    def jiraIDsFuncHelper(self, data, location, value=None):
        tracker = data
        for i, key in enumerate(location):
            if i == len(location) - 1:
                if not value:
                    return tracker.get(key)
                tracker.update({key : value})
            else:
                temp = tracker.get(key)
                if not temp:
                    tracker.update({key : {}})
                    tracker = tracker.get(key)
                else:
                    tracker = temp
        return data

    def request_GET(self, ticket, forceCustomURL=None):
        headers = {
            "Authorization" : "Basic " + self.b64Auth,
            "Content-Type"  : "application/json"
        }
        if forceCustomURL:
            req = Request(forceCustomURL, headers=headers)
        else:
            time.sleep(float(random.randint(0,self.randRequestDeley))/10)
            req = Request(self.RESTuri + "issue/" + ticket, headers=headers)
        resp = urlopen(req)
        if resp.headers.dict["x-seraph-loginreason"].upper() != "OUT, OK":
            raise ValueError("Invalid Credentials")
        return json.loads(resp.read())

    def request_POST_search(self, query):
        headers = {
            "Authorization" : "Basic " + self.b64Auth,
            "Content-Type"  : "application/json"
        }
        time.sleep(float(random.randint(0,self.randRequestDeley))/10)
        req = Request(self.RESTuri + "search", data=json.dumps(query), headers=headers)
        resp = urlopen(req)
        respStr = resp.read()
        if respStr == '':
            return None
        return json.loads(respStr)

    def request_PUT(self, ticket, data):
        headers = {
            "Authorization" : "Basic " + self.b64Auth,
            "Content-Type"  : "application/json"
        }
        time.sleep(float(random.randint(0,self.randRequestDeley))/10)
        req = Request(self.RESTuri + "issue/" + ticket, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
        req.get_method = lambda: "PUT"
        resp = urlopen(req)
        respStr = resp.read()
        if respStr == '':
            return None
        return json.loads(respStr)



jiraIDs = {
        "Epic Link"   : lambda jiraInstance,data,value=None: jiraInstance.jiraIDsFuncHelper(data,["fields","customfield_11913"],value=value),
        "is blocked by" : lambda jiraInstance,data,value=None: jiraInstance.jiraIDsFuncHelper(data,["fields","customfield_15802"],value=value),
        "type"        : lambda jiraInstance,data,value=None: jiraInstance.jiraIDsFuncHelper(data,["fields","issuetype","name"],value=value),
        "status"        : lambda jiraInstance,data,value=None: jiraInstance.jiraIDsFuncHelper(data,["fields","status","name"],value=value),
        "labels"        : lambda jiraInstance,data,value=None: jiraInstance.jiraIDsFuncHelper(data,["fields","labels"],value=value),
    }

getSearchQueryTemplate = lambda: copy.deepcopy({
                                                    "jql" : None,
                                                    "fields" : ["id", "key", "summary"],
                                                    "maxResults" : 1000000,    
                                                })
```

Comment: Code would be nice...

Comment: Only thing I can possibly think of is if a thread reads the same variable at the same time, but that is only a read and not a write to the variable.